# Is there any way to start XAxis from 1 instead of 0

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

I created JSFiddle here [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/nparikh/0xm9kLqu/36/)
[image]
Here I want to start from 1 at XAxis instead of 0

**in below screen shot, I want Oct 20 at Nov 20 place**

[image]

```
>   var xScaleTest =  d3.scaleTime()
                    .domain([new Date("2020-10-01"), new Date("2021-09-30")])
                    .range([0,  width-margin*2]);
```

> > `/* Add Axis into SVG */ var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScaleTest).ticks(12).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b -%y"));`

Comment: So do you mean that you want some extra padding before the graph starts? Or did you maybe confuse the x and y axes? Please add a [mre] of your code, so we can see what you mean and better help you

Comment: I added screen shot of What I am getting right now and What I want.  I want to skip 0 position of xAxis

Comment: I updated question with JSFiddle here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this by using [`d3.timeMonth.every`](https://github.com/d3/d3-time#interval_every) to make a tick on the first day of every month, and then by extending the domain. Note how all the ticks are there, and there is extra space on both sides of the axis

```js
const x = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([new Date("2020-9-15"), new Date("2021-10-15")])
  .range([50, 550]);

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
  .ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(1))
  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b -%y"));

d3.select("svg")
  .append("g")
  .call(xAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600"></svg>
```

---

If you cannot adjust the domain, you can manually make it longer on both sides by overriding the `.domain` path:

```js
const margin = 20;
const offsetX = 30;

const x = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([new Date("2020-10-01"), new Date("2021-9-30")])
  // Narrow the range here
  .range([margin + offsetX, 600 - margin - offsetX]);

const y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 10])
  .range([100, margin]);

const ticks = d3.timeMonths(x.domain()[0], x.domain()[1]);
if (ticks[0].getMonth() !== x.domain()[0].getMonth()) {
  // Oct 1rst gets rounded up to November because of timezones
  ticks.unshift(x.domain()[0]);
}

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
  .tickValues(ticks)
  .tickSizeOuter(0) // Don't show the ticks at the edges of the domain
  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b -%y"));

d3.select("svg")
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0, 100)")
  .call(xAxis)
  .select('.domain')
  .attr('d', "M" + (x.range()[0] - offsetX) + ",0.5 H" + (x.range()[1] + offsetX));

d3.select("svg")
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin + ", 0)")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.js"></script>
<svg width="600"></svg>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223401/discussion-between-ruben-helsloot-and-niti-parikh).